# SQL Server Express ... Stored Proceedure "Null Parameter" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Using Visual Studio 2010 I am putting together a quick .NET application that needs to record some data.  I am using the built in facility of SQL Server Express and have created a Stored Proceedure for the data insertion.  I have setup the database table to allows Nulls on the field in question, but am generating a runtime exception "Procedure or function 'XYZ' expects parameter '@ErrorCode', which was not supplied."

I have tried creating the SqlParameters the "plain way":

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ErrorCode", state.ErrorCode));
```

I have also tried creating them by setting more of the properties:

```
SqlParameter errorCodeParam = new SqlParameter("ErrorCode", SqlDbType.Int);
errorCodeParam.IsNullable = true;
errorCodeParam.Value = state.ErrorCode;
command.Parameters.Add( errorCodeParam );
```

My ErrorCode property on the state object is simply a nullable int .... "int?" with an assigned value of "null".  As the table column for this field supposedly allows nulls I'm a bit stumpped on why it's complaining.

Thoughts or ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: In your procedure have you declared the parameter like this

@MyParam MyDataType Null

The null isn't implicit on the procedure you have to declare it that way.

Comment: Admittedly I didn't.  But, when I modified it it won't allow me to save it.  I receive a compilation error of "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'Null'.  Must declare the scaler variable "@ErrorCode". Must declare the scaler variable "@PrimaryKey"."  What's interesting about this is I have another nullable int that preceeds this param called @StatusCode, and the system doesn't complain about that one.  Hum??

Answer (score 1):

After some additional experimentation I found the answer (thought I'd pass it along in case someone else runs into the same situation).  I have been using statements like the following:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ErrorCode", (state.ErrorCode != null ? state.ErrorCode : null)));
```

Whereby I am checking the value of a nullable int (int?) to see if has a value, and if not, assigning a C# null to a SqlParameter .... *which wants a DBNull.Value instead*.